# Creating a new key after a target index in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to store the each image path in the db. I want to append each image an epoch time stamp with its name. Let's look here.

```
$base = 'uploads/testpic.png';
$explode = explode('.', $base);
```

so if i print_r($explode) here i get

```
Array
(
    [0] = testpic
    [1] = png
)
```

now i want to insert a new key after index 0 here which will contain `time()` function value. 
so the array will look something like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] = testpic
    [1] = 12313485 //the epoch time 
    [2] = png
)
```

and later will implode the array again so finaly each image will get a non-duplicate 
name somethng like this : `uploads/testpic12313485.png`

how i can acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new array:

```
$newArr = [$explode[0], time(), $explode[1]];
```

While inserting into an array is *possible*, it is not *trivial* even in PHP. You need to loop through the array backwards, shifting all elements up an index until you hit your target for insertion.

Even then, numerically-indexed arrays are not contiguous in PHP, eg you can wind up with arrays like:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
}
```

Which is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't answer how to insert an array element in the middle of an array, but I would do something like this:

```
$parts = pathinfo($base);
$newname = $parts['filename'] . time() . $parts['extension'];
```

Make use of the tools that are provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [substr_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) and insert timestamp into string...

```
<?php
    $base = 'uploads/testpic.png';
    $explode = explode('.', $base);
    $newstr = substr_replace($base,time(),strpos($base,"."),0);
    var_dump($newstr);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you all guys. Actually i really appreciate for showing all possible ways to get what i was looking for. Amazing replies!